# Will ndb work with entities that were created without using ndb on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Switching to the `ndb` library on python GAE.

Can I use `ndb` with entities that were created previously using the low-level api? Or do I have to copy all the old entities and re-save them in order to use ndb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ndb` is simply a wrapper API. The core datastore is based on protocol buffers, and doesn't care what you use to access it. In other words, yes AFAIK it should work just fine.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow You could also use db and ndb in the same app.. there is no problem even mixing them.. `to_old_key()` and `from_old_key()` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_to_old_key